# jQuery reset toggle in navigation menu

Tags: jquery, menu, toggle, reset

I am fairly new to jQuery and I am having an issue with a current project I'm working on.

I've been looking at other questions with similar issues, but in their cases the solutions have not worked for me.

On this site the user will click a link in a navigation list which will slide out a div containing the information. I used the toggle command because i want to be able to close show and hide the div by clicking the same link, I also want to be able to hide the active div by clicking on a different link, which currently works great. The problem is when clicking a different link and hiding the content, you have to double click the previously link in order to reset the toggle.

How can I reset this toggle so the user doesn't have to double click?

here is a link to the site [www.RickPatinoPhotography.com](http://www.rickpatinophotography.com)

my code:

```js
//Slide Bio Div
    $('#showBio').toggle(function() {
            //shows Bio div
        $('#bio').animate({ marginLeft: '+=1316px'}, 500);
            //hides other divs if showing
        $('#work').animate({ marginLeft: '0px'}, 500);
        $('#contact').animate({ marginLeft: '0px'}, 500);
    }, function () {
            //returns Bio div to default state      
        $('#bio').animate({ marginLeft: '0px'}, 500);
    });

//Slide Work Div
    $('#showWork').toggle(function() {
            //shows Work div
        $('#work').animate({ marginLeft: '+=1316px'}, 500);
            //hides other divs if showing
        $('#bio').animate({ marginLeft: '0px'}, 500);
        $('#contact').animate({ marginLeft: '0px'}, 500);
            //returns Contact div to default state  
        }, function () {
        $('#work').animate({ marginLeft: '0px'}, 500);
    }); 

//Slide Contact Div
    $('#showContact').toggle(function() {
            //shows Contact div
        $('#contact').animate({ marginLeft: '+=1316px'}, 500);
            //hides other divs if showing
        $('#work').animate({ marginLeft: '0px'}, 500);
        $('#bio').animate({ marginLeft: '0px'}, 500);
            //returns Contact div to default state  
    }, function () {
        $('#contact').animate({ marginLeft: '0px'}, 500);
    }); 
});
```

**EDIT:**
Well I was able to come up with a solution, I was able to creat a basic .click function along with an if/else statement that works like a champ. Thanks to all for looking.

**new code:**

```
    //Slide Bio Div
    $('#showBio a').click(function() {
            //shows Bio div
        if ($('#bio').css("marginLeft") == "1316px"){
            $('#bio').animate({ marginLeft: '0px'}, 500);
        } else {
            $('#bio').animate({ marginLeft: '+=1316px'}, 500);
            //hides other divs if showing
            $('#work, #contact').animate({ marginLeft: '0px'}, 500);        
            $('#showBio a').addClass('activePage');
            $('#showWork a, #showContact a').removeClass('activePage');
            $("#showBio li, #showBio a").click(false);
        }
    });

//Slide Work Div
    $('#showWork a').click(function() {
            //shows Bio div
        if ($('#work').css("marginLeft") == "1316px"){
            $('#work').animate({ marginLeft: '0px'}, 500);
        } else {
            $('#work').animate({ marginLeft: '+=1316px'}, 500);
                //hides other divs if showing
            $('#bio, #contact').animate({ marginLeft: '0px'}, 500);
            $('#showWork a').addClass('activePage');
            $('#showBio a, #showContact a').removeClass('activePage');
        }
    }); 

//Slide Contact Div
    $('#showContact a').click(function() {
                //shows Bio div
        if ($('#contact').css("marginLeft") == "1316px"){
            $('#contact').animate({ marginLeft: '0px'}, 500);
        } else {
            $('#contact').animate({ marginLeft: '+=1316px'}, 500);
                //hides other divs if showing
            $('#work, #bio').animate({ marginLeft: '0px'}, 500);
            $('#showContent a').addClass('activePage');
            $('#showWork a, #showBio a').removeClass('activePage');
        }
    }); 
});
```